# Next and previous character in uppercase

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, dosbox

I'm new to assembly, also I'm using DOSBox

I'm trying to print, in uppercase, the alphabetically preceding and following letter of a lower case letter entered by the user. (eg. if the user enters `c`, it will print `B` and `D`)

But my code print weird samples.

My code:

```
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 100H
    .DATA
    MSG1 DB "Enter a letter between a and z:$"
    MSG2 DB "The previous letter is:$"
    MSG3 DB "The next letter is:$"
    X    DB ?
    .CODE
    MAIN PROC
    ; initialize DS
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    ; print MSG1
    LEA DX, MSG1
    MOV AH, 9h
    INT 21H
    ; read lowercase letter
    MOV AH,1h
    INT 21H
    ; save the letter X
    MOV X, AL
    ; printing new line
    MOV DL, 10
    MOV AH, 02h
    INT 21h
    MOV DL, 13
    MOV AH, 02h
    INT 21h
    ; print MSG2
    MOV AH, 9h
    LEA DX, MSG2
    INT 21H
    ; The previous letter
    MOV DL, X
    SUB DL, 1
    ADD DL, 48
    MOV AH, 2h
    INT 21H
    ; print MSG3
    MOV AH, 9h
    LEA DX, MSG3
    INT 21H
    ; The previous letter
    MOV DL, X
    ADD DL, 1
    ADD DL, 48
    MOV AH, 2h
    INT 21H
    ; DOS exit
    MOV AH, 4CH
    INT 21H
    MAIN ENDP
    END MAIN
```

Comment: Why do you `ADD DL, 48`? That's only needed for integer to text conversion but you are not doing any of that.

Comment: what should I do then ?

Comment: How about you delete those? The rest seems okay. Oh you need upper case too ... well then change `add dl, 1` to `sub dl, 31` and the `sub dl, 1` to `sub dl, 33`.

Comment: The code does not convert lowercase to uppercase - probably you wanted to use the "magic" `add dl, 48` for that because "it works" for numbers. Look at any ASCII table! To convert to uppercase, use `sub dl,32` . In addition, you probably should not ask for an input "a to z" but rather for "b to y".

Comment: @Jester it Worked.. I can't express how my I love you for answering me. I was stuck 3 days trying to find what wrong with my code.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer.

Comment: You should post the answer you edited into your question as its own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following
look:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
MSG1 DB 0DH,0AH,'Enter a lowerCase letter between a and z :$'
MSG2 DB 0DH,0AH,'Tht previous letter is :$'
MSG3 DB 0DH,0AH,'The next letter is:$'
.CODE
MAIN PROC
MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX
LEA DX,MSG1 
MOV AH,9 
INT 21H 
MOV AH,1 
INT 21H 
LEA DX,MSG2 
MOV AH,9 
INT 21H 
MOV AH,2 
SUB AL,20H 
SUB AL,1H
MOV BL,AL 
MOV DL,BL 
INT 21H
LEA DX,MSG3
MOV AH,9
INT 21H
MOV AH,2
ADD AL,2H
MOV DL,AL
INT 21H
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```